# Using LINQ how do I concatenate bytes from SortedDictionary<string,List<byte[]>>

Tags: arrays, linq, concatenation

I have a `SortedDictionary<string,List<byte[]>>`
I need to concatenate all the byte[] arrays starting from the first till the last.

How can I do this using LINQ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to flatten two levels of hierarchy:

```
d.Values.SelectMany(c => c.SelectMany(b => b))
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, for those of us (like me) who can never remember `SelectMany`'s syntax, you can also do exactly the same thing with multiple `from` clauses:

```
var bytes = 
    (from byteList in dictionary.Values
     from b in byteList
     select b)
```

which gives `bytes` as an `IEnumerable<byte>`.